# PHPStorm SVN history endless loop after copying file from branch to trunk then reintegrating

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch, phpstorm

I am using PHPstorm to work on this project, and lately "show history" runs at what appears to be an endless loop. It wasn't always like this, but Now the repository is displaying signs of distress when using PHPStorm to attempt to view the svn history. However, simply doing `svn log -v` on shell works fine obviously.
There is one historic issue which may be responsible for this, and I believe only a true SVN expert can help me fix it, or let me know how to fix this issue:

1. I once took a branch from the trunk, and added a new file on the branch.
2. Then I needed that file in the trunk, so I copied it using `svn cp` from the branch into the trunk.
3. And only three months later, I reintegrated the branch...
4. After a while, a new symptom started to appear: each time I'd create a branch, and merge from the trunk into the branch, the same copied file appeared to have mergeinfo changes, even though nothing was changed. The same file kept popping up and again in all sorts of merges, with only mergeinfo being updated, only for this one single "special" file.

How can I fix this thing, which appears to be a historic error on my part, in order to make PHPStorm stop getting confused when logging all mergeinfo changes, and entering into what appears to be this cyclic recursion?